# when he poured / when he was pouring / while pouring

Tags: past-tense, gerunds

> He was burned **when he poured** boiling water into the mug.
>
> He was burned **when he was pouring** boiling water into the mug.

Which tense is better to use here if the action isn't long? Can we use Past Continuous even if the action lasted only 3-5 seconds?

If I have such kind of dilemma, can I say instead: "He was burned **while pouring** boiling water into the mug."?

Comment: If the injury was caused by the water, then "scalded" would be better than "burned".  See dictionary

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In this case, I assume that your main point is simply to link the two events, the pouring and the burning—"He poured some boiling water, and that explains how he got burned"—*not* to emphasize their precise timing. In that case, "when he poured" and "while pouring" are both good choices.

The past continuous only becomes the *best* choice when we have reason to *emphasize* the concurrency of the two events. "Oh, this burn on my ear? I tried to answer the phone *while I was* ironing." The punchline hinges on the fact that I was immediately in the act of operating the iron when the phone rang.